# Div inside td has a 1 px border. How can it be removed?

Tags: html, html-table, border

I have a div inside a td and I can't seem to remove a 1 px border around it.
If I try adding `td {padding:0}`, the border disappears, but the div jumps to the left, and the variable td's automatically change to 0px width.
How can I remove the border around the div without messing up the whole table?

```
HTML:

<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="header-left"></td>
        <td class="header">
            <div class="header-image"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="header-right"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

CSS:

table {
width:100%;
border-spacing: 0;
}

.header-left {
height:100px;
background-image:url(img/header-left.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;

}

.header-right {
height:100px;
background-image:url(img/header.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

.header {
height:100px;
width:960px;
background-image:url(img/header.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
margin:0 auto;
}

.header-image {
height:100px;
width:548px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-image:url(img/header-image.png);
}
```

Comment: Can you share a fiddle example for this...?

Answer (score 0):

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"></table>
```

This way there won't be any spacing around td's you create within a table.

Comment: Hi. This solution seems to have the same issue as my td {padding:0} attempt. The border around the div disappears, but the div jumps to the left. .header-left and .header-right get a width of 0 and .header gets a width of 1903 (screen width).

Comment: To get the header to the right we can apply a float:right; to the header-image.

But can you tell me what you're trying to create? Because right now, I got rid of your border. And your image is on the right side of the header.

Answer (score 0):

ADD THE FOLLOWING CODE IN THE DIV TAG

```
<DIV class ="header-image" style="border:0px">
```

or if you have problem with table border then SET  `table border=0`

Comment: if my answer helped you dont frget to mark it as correct and up vote for me . i will be there for any doubts you have

Comment: I tried both variants but they don't work. The div still has a border. The other elements of the table look fine.

Comment: inside the class header-image write border:0px

Comment: or remove the class ="header-image" if not needed

Comment: I already tried it twice and it had no effect. I sadly need the header-image class.

Comment: is the border around the image file ?

Comment: I found a weird solution: I applied a reset.css (which implies I apply the td {padding:0} ). I then set the header-left and -right widths to 50%. Then I set the header-image width to 960px (to match the content wrapper). Now the picture hangs at the left of the content, NOT the left of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

you need to just set properties of table as like below

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
```

In css changes try below

```
table { border:none;}
```

if still didnt get solutions give me example that have border around div because here i cant see any border around div

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Border:none in class header
or
creat class global 
table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0; }